# react native testing snapshot with multiple state renders?

Tags: react-native, react-native-testing-library

I have a component that sets state several times in its `componentDidMount` method.  For example:

```
componentDidMount = async () => {
  this.setState({ waiting: true });
  try {
    const data = await this.fetchData();

    this.setState({ data })
  } catch (err) {
  } finally {
    this.setState({ waiting: false });
  }
};
```

With a render method akin to:

```
render() {
    if (this.state.waiting) {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }

    return (
       ... actual view ...
    )
}
```

I can run a test with `react-native-testing-library`

```
const tree = testing.render(<HomeScreen {...props} />);
```

And yet I only ever get the waiting view. However, when I step through the test the other renders are hit.

So it seems that the snapshot testing is only capturing the *first* render. Is there a way to have it give me the *final* render?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I needed to wait for the microtasks.

```
await testing.flushMicrotasksQueue();
```

Did the trick